# I've got run time error 1004 while merging several excels into a single one

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have got this error massage during merging the content of several excel files into one. I know this occurs because there is not much space left.
Can anyone help me how to include a rule like if the space is not enough then open a new worksheet and paste the remaining content there?

This is it:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\JudakV\Desktop\xxxmacro\")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        Range("A2:IV" & Range("1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

        Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

There is a report of mine which requires to copy and paste the content of several (about 20) excel files into one single file, and if it has more than 1M rows (usually more than that) then open a new worksheet and copy the remaining part there.
I am not good at macros, but it could spare lots of time for me if it would work. But I am troubling with the page limit and to open a new worksheet part kind of stuff...

Comment: Not clear what you mean with `merge` - put all data into one sheet? A sheet (of an xlsm-file) can hold more than a million rows, but I doubt that you will get happy with such a file. Anyway, show your code if you want to get help with that.

Answer (score 0):

This code will copy the data to new sheets.  I haven't tested on massive amounts of data, but should work.

```
Public Sub XLMerger()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oDir As Object
    Dim oFiles As Object
    Dim oFle As Object
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim tgtLastCell As Range 'Target last cell.
    Dim srcLastCell As Range 'Source last cell.
    Dim lRequiredRows As Long
    Dim lAvailableRows As Long
    Dim tgtSheet As Worksheet

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oDir = oFSO.GetFolder(""C:\Users\JudakV\Desktop\xxxmacro\"")
    Set oFiles = oDir.Files

    'Will be pasting data into this sheet.
    Set tgtSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each oFle In oFiles
        If InStr(oFle.Type, "Excel") > 0 Then
            Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oFle, ReadOnly:=True)

            'Set reference to last cell on Target sheet.
            With tgtSheet
                'If there is data on the very last row an
                'incorrect reference will be returned.
                If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1) <> "" Then
                    Set tgtLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
                Else
                    Set tgtLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                End If
            End With

            With wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                'Set reference to last cell on Source sheet.
                Set srcLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

                'Will it fit?
                lRequiredRows = srcLastCell.Row - 1
                lAvailableRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count - tgtLastCell.Row

                If lRequiredRows <= lAvailableRows Then
                    'Straight Copy/Paste as it all fits.
                    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(srcLastCell.Row, 256)).Copy
                    tgtLastCell.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Else
                    'Copy what we can onto old sheet providing there's at least 1 blank row.
                    If lAvailableRows > 0 Then
                        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lAvailableRows + 1, 256)).Copy
                        tgtLastCell.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If

                    'Create a new sheet, copy headings over and paste remaining data.
                    'The IIF command ensures lAvailable rows isn't looking at row 0.
                    Set tgtSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Copy Destination:=tgtSheet.Range("A1")
                    .Range(.Cells(lAvailableRows + IIf(lAvailableRows = 0, 2, 0), 1), .Cells(srcLastCell.Row, 256)).Copy
                    tgtSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                End If

            End With
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wrkBk.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next oFle

End Sub
```

Comment: it looks good, but I have got a run time error no.9 "Subscript out of range", I think it is because of the high number of the rows included. Maybe can you think of a solution for this? Thank you very much for your help again!

Comment: What line does the error occur on? I've got a feeling one of the workbooks  you're opening doesn't have a sheet called `Sheet1`.